# There exists a subsequence that converges to f pointwise a.e .

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $f,f_k,\,k\in\mathbb{N}$, be measurable functions on a measurable set $E\subset\mathbb{R}$.
If  $$\lim_{k \to \infty}\int_{E} \frac{|f_k(x)-f(x)|}{1+|f_k(x)-f(x)|}\, dx=0,$$ 
show that there exists a subsequence that converges to f pointwise a.e .

I have a idea that "Since $f_k$ converges to $f$ in measure, it has a subsequence that converges to $f$ pointwise a.e."
But I dont know how to prove that $f_k$ converges to f in measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting that the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}$ is increasing for $x>-1$, therefor for $|f_k(x)-f(x)|\ge\sigma$, one has
$$ \frac{|f_k(x)-f(x)|}{1+|f_k(x)-f(x)|}\ge\frac{\sigma}{1+\sigma}. $$
Let $E_k(\sigma)=\{x\in E: |f_k(x)-f(x)|\ge \sigma\}$.
$$ \int_{E}\frac{|f_k(x)-f(x)|}{1+|f_k(x)-f(x)|}dx\ge\int_{E_k(\sigma)}\frac{|f_k(x)-f(x)|}{1+|f_k(x)-f(x)|}dx\ge \frac{\sigma}{1+\sigma}|E_k(\sigma)|.$$
Letting $k\to\infty$, one has $|E_k(\sigma)|\to 0$, for $\forall \sigma>0$. Thus $f_k(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ in measure.

Comment: Thanks very much for your very clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

As is well known, if $g_k \to g$ in $L^p, p\ge 1,$ then there is a subsequence $g_k$ that converges pointwise a.e.to $g.$ Your hypothesis implies $g_k(x)=|f_k(x)-f(x)|/(1+|f_k(x)-f(x)|) \to 0$ in $L^1(E).$ Thus there is a subsequence $g_{k_j} \to 0$ pointwise a.e. Now if $y_n$ is a sequence in $[0,\infty),$ then $y_n/(1+y_n) \to 0$ iff $y_n \to 0.$ Thus $f_{k_j} \to 0$ pointwise a.e.